# Python solutions for live packet capture at high packet rates

Tags: python, packet-sniffers

What are my options in `python` to capture live streaming packets from an `1/10Gbps` network interface without packet loss?.
I came across many libraries such as `Scapy`, `Pyshark`, `Pcapy`, `Pypcap`. But I couldn't find their `performance-metrics` regarding capture rate, i.e up to what packet rate they can sniff 100% packets? something like [pfring-ZC](https://www.ntop.org/products/packet-capture/pf_ring/pf_ring-zc-zero-copy/) for `C`.
Are there any `Python` libraries which captures packets at `1Gbps` line rate?, what are my options?

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt Python is really adequate for this kinds of speeds.

Comment: @Cukic0d Okay, Any idea which is the best among the above mentioned (not only these) libraries in terms of speed. Where can I see their capture speed metrics?

Comment: How about using `raw-socket` in python can this capture at higher packet rate?

Comment: The thing is, regardless of the tool you're using, if you're not reading packets fast enough (because for instance, python is too slow), the kernel will fill the entire allocated buffer and will start discarding any further packets.

Comment: I would recommend looking at these [benchmark tests](http://libtins.github.io/benchmark) for various packet sniffer frameworks.